# Ascending order with three integers for C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    cout << "Please input three integers:" << endl;
    cout << ">> ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << endl;

    if (((a == a) && (b > a)) && (c >= a))
    {
        cout << "Input three integer numbers in ascending order:" << endl;
        cout << a << " " << c << " " << b;
    }
    else if (((a == a) && (b >= a)) && (c >= a))
    {
        cout << "Input three integer numbers in ascending order:" << endl;
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    }
    else if (((a > b) && (b == b)) && (c >= b))
    {
        cout << "Input three integer numbers in ascending order:" << endl;
        cout << b << " " << c << " " << a;
    }
    else if (((a >= b) && (b == b)) && (c < b))
    {
        cout << "Input three integer numbers in ascending order:" << endl;
        cout << c << " " << a << " " << b;
    }
    else if (((a > c) && (b >= c)) && (c == c))
    {
        cout << "Input three integer numbers in ascending order:" << endl;
        cout << c << " " << b << " " << a;
    }
    else if (((a >= c) && (b <= c)) && (c == c))
    {
        cout << "Input three integer numbers in ascending order:" << endl;
        cout << b << " " << c << " " << a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For this assignment, I used 1, 2, and 3 for entering the integer. 
My question is why these input (1, 2, 3) and (2, 1, 3) and (3, 2, 1)
don't ascended properl?

Comment: What is the point of checking for variable self-equality? (a == a, b == b, c == c)?

Comment: Perhaps you should attempt to *debug* your code? Please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: @AlexanderBily It was just a test and you passed! I think...

Comment: btw if you use blank lines a bit more sparingly and use a function your code could fit on a couple of lines

Comment: Try to get it workling with two numbers, and try lots of combinations; both equal, first < second, first > second. Then try it with three.

Comment: _"don't ascended properl"_ is not an acceptable problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right number of cases (6 possible orderings) but the conditions are wrong. I will only go through the first one...

```
if (((a == a) && (b > a)) && (c >= a)) {
        cout << a << " " << c << " " << b;
}
```

An input that would pass the condition is `a=1`,`b=2`, `c=3`, but `1 3 2` is not the correct order. To be certain that `a c b` is ascending, you need

```
if (( c >= a) && (b >= c))
```

(You dont need a third one here, because by transitivity, if `c>=a` and `b>=c` then also `b>=a` holds.

Comment: got upvotes even if the answer was obvioulsy wrong ;) fixed now

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you can alternatively use `std::sort` found in `algorithm` header.

```
int vals[] { 3, 1, 2 };
std::sort(vals, vals + 3);
cout << vals[0] << vals[1] << vals[2]; // prints 123
```

Comment: This is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to make sure the numbers entered are in ascending order. A single test can make sure of that.

```
do {
     cout << "Enter 3 numbers in ascending order: ";
     cin >> arr[0] >> arr[1] >> arr[2];
} while (!(arr[0] <= arr[1] && arr[1] <= arr[2]));
```

Comment: Two equal valued numbers are considered in ascending order, so all `<` should be `<=`